# Prove limiting behaviour of solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem
$$
\begin{align*}
\dot x&=x(y^2-x^2),\\\\
\dot y&=-y^2, \\\\
x(0)&=(x_0,y_0)
\end{align*}
$$
where $y_0>x_0>0$. Say $\phi(t)$ is the solution of this IVP (with maximal domain). Since $\dot y=-y^2$ yields a maximal solution $y(t)$ that exists on $(a,\infty)$ with $a>\infty$, one can argue that $\phi(t)$ has also lower bound $a$. I want to argue that
$$
\lim_{t\to b^{+}}x(t)=0.
$$
We know that $x(t)$ descreases monotonically as $t$ decreases. Therefore the limit $\lim_{t\to a^+}x(t)$ exists and has to be at least $0$:
$$
L=\lim_{t\to a^+}x(t)\geq 0.
$$
I want to arrive at a contradiction if $\lim_{t\to a^+}x(t)>0$.

**My attempt:**

Let's consider the system
$$
\begin{align*}
\dot x&=-x(y^2-x^2),\\\\
\dot y&=y^2, \\\\
x(0)&=(x_0,y_0)
\end{align*}
$$
whose solutions are the same as for the original solution, except the direction of the time has been reversed. We can compute the solution to $\dot y=y^2$ explicitly: $y(t)=\frac{y_0}{1-y_0t}$ for $t<y_0^{-1}$. Note that if the solution $(x(t),y(t))$ doesn't not exist on $[0,y_0^{-1})$, then $(x(t),y(t))$ would be contained in a compact set for positive time, and since it converges (by monotonicity), it would have to converge to a fixed point, which is not possible. Hence $(x(t),y(t))$ exists on $[0,y_0^{-1})$ and
$$
L=\lim_{t\to (v_0^{-1})^-}x(t)\geq 0
$$
since the solution can't cross the $y$-axis (which already contains solutions).

Assume for a contradiction that $L>0$. Then
$$
\lim_{t\to (v_0^{-1})^-}\dot x(t)=-\infty,
$$
since $\lim_{t\to (v_0^{-1})^-} y(t)=\infty$. Now I somehow need to arrive at a contradiction, knowing that $x(t)$ is bounded, monotonic and continuously differentiable on $(\delta,v_0^{-1})$ (for some $\delta$ close enough to $v_0^{-1}$).

Comment: Hint: Personally, I would consider the backward-in-time system, (i.e. multiplying by -1 the right-hand side) and study the behaviour as t\to b^-...just because I prefer to go forward :)...
Then, we can explicitly write the solution to $y'(t)=y(t)^2$, $y(0)=y_0>0$, i.e.
$$
y(t)=\frac{y_0}{1-y_0t},\;\;\;t\in [0, \frac{1}{y_0}]
$$
Then, we have to study the first equation that becomes a scalar non-autonomous ODE. And I think that you can then prove by contradiction, via your argument...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all solutions behave as you describe, and this can be seen by solving the system explicitly.

Allow me to change $t$ to $-t$, so that the system becomes
$$
\dot x = x(x^2-y^2)
,\qquad
\dot y = y^2
,\qquad
(x(0),y(0))=(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbf{R}_+^2
.
$$
Since we're looking at solutions in the positive quadrant, we get an equivalent system by setting $(u,v)=(x^2,y)$:
$$
\dot u = 2u(u-v^2)
,\qquad
\dot v = v^2
,\qquad
(u(0),v(0))=(u_0,v_0) \in \mathbf{R}_+^2
.
$$
From $\dot v = v^2$ with $v(0)=v_0>0$ we get
$$
v(t) = \frac{v_0}{1-v_0 t}
,\qquad
\text{for}
\quad
t < \frac{1}{v_0}
.
$$
We can insert this into the equation for $u$:
$$
\dot u + 2v(t)^2 u = 2u^2
,\qquad
u(0) = u_0 > 0
.
$$
This is a Bernoulli ODE, which is linearized by the change of dependent variable $w(t) = 1/u(t)$ (where we don't have to worry about division by zero, since $u$ is positive):
$$
\dot u + 2v(t)^2 u = 2u^2
\iff
\frac{\dot u}{u^2} + \frac{2v(t)^2}{u} = 2
\iff
\dot w - 2v(t)^2 w = -2
.
$$
Since $v^2=\dot v$ we can write this as
$$
\dot w + (-2 \dot v(t)) w = -2
,\qquad
w(0) = 1/u_0 > 0
,
$$
and multiply by the integrating factor $\exp(-2 v(t))$, which gives
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \Bigl( w(t) e^{-2v(t)} \Bigr) = -2 e^{-2v(t)}
,\qquad
w(0) = 1/u_0 > 0
.
$$
Integrating, we obtain
$$
e^{-2v(t)} w(t) - e^{-2v(0)} w(0) = -2 \int_0^t e^{-2v(s)} ds
,
$$
or in other words
$$
w(t) = e^{2v(t)} \biggl( \frac{e^{-2 v_0}}{u_0} - 2 \int_0^t e^{-2v(s)} ds \biggr)
.
$$
Going back to $u=1/w$, the solution of the system for $(u,v)$ is therefore
$$
u(t) = \frac{u_0}{\displaystyle e^{2v(t)} \biggl( e^{-2v_0} - 2u_0 \int_0^t e^{-2v(s)} ds \biggr)}
,\qquad
v(t) = \frac{v_0}{1-v_0 t}
.
$$
The interval of existence for this solution depends on the relation between $u_0 > 0$ and $v_0 > 0$. If
$$
u_0
\le \frac{e^{-2v_0}}{\displaystyle 2 \int_0^{1/v_0} e^{-2v(s)} ds}
= \frac{e^{-2v_0}}{\displaystyle 2 \biggl( \frac{1}{v_0 e^{2v_0}} + 2 \operatorname{Ei}(-2v_0) \biggr)}
= \frac{v_0}{\displaystyle 2 \bigl( 1 + 2 v_0 e^{2v_0} \operatorname{Ei}(-2v_0) \bigr)}
$$
(where the integral is evaluated in terms of the special function $\operatorname{Ei}(z) = -\int_{-z}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t} dt$
by substituting $r=2v_0/(1-v_0s)$ and then integrating by parts),
then the solution lives for as long as $v(t)$ does, i.e., for $t < 1/v_0$,
since the bracket in the expression for $u(t)$ remains positive for those $t$.
And if the strict inequality $u_0 < (\cdots)$ holds, then indeed $u(t) \to 0$ as $t \to (1/v_0)^-$, since the bracket tends to a positive value, while $e^{2v(t)} \to +\infty$.

But if the reverse inequality holds, $u_0 > (\cdots)$, then the denominator in the expression for $u(t)$ becomes zero at some earlier time, say $t_0$ with $0 < t_0 < 1/v_0$, so that the lifespan of the solution is just $t<t_0$, with  $u(t) \to +\infty$ as $t \to t_0^-$.

So there is a separatrix
$$
u = \frac{v}{\displaystyle 2 \bigl( 1 + 2 v e^{2v} \operatorname{Ei}(-2v) \bigr)}
$$
in the phase portrait, and the fate of the solution is determined by on which side of this curve that the starting point $(u_0,v_0)$ lies.

Here's the phase portrait in the $(u,v)$-plane, with the $u$-nullcline $u=v^2$ in purple, and the separatrix in red:

[image: Phase portrait in the (u,v)-plane.]

Curves starting below the separatrix go off to the right ($u \to +\infty$, $v$ tends to a constant). And curves starting above it approach the $v$-axis ($u \to 0$, $v \to +\infty$).

(And everything is of course easily translated back to the original variables $(x,y)=(\sqrt{u},v)$, where the nullcline becomes the straight line $y=x$, and the separatrix becomes some curve below that line.)

Comment: (I might add a figure of the phase portrait later, but I don't have time right now.)

Comment: Wow, thank you! I forgot to mention that I was looking also at $y_0>x_0$, instead of just $x_0,y_0>0$. Good to see that a straightforward solution might not exist (previously I asked myself the same question with $\dot y=-y$ instead of $\dot y=-y^2$, and then the argument was simple, since the solution existed for all time). It's useful for me to know that these considerations can be non-trivial. I will have to go through your solution, to see if I understand it. (No need to include the phase portrait as far as I'm concerned, free online phase plotters are readily available).

Comment: +1! Performing a change of variable to get a Bernoulli equation was very neat.

Comment: OK, with $y_0>x_0$ it's much easier, since then your argument works right away!

Comment: Now I've added a phase portrait anyway, just because it's gratifying to see that the equation for the separatrix is doing it's job correctly. :-)

Comment: Problem is that I couldn't formalise my argument. However, it's okay if that is left unresolved, as I have an explicit solution now.

Comment: How about this? With $y_0 > x_0$, we know that $y(t) \nearrow +\infty$ and $x(t) \searrow L$ as $t \to (1/y_0)^-$, for some $L \ge 0$. Suppose that $L>0$. We can view $x$ as a function of $y$, which satisfies $$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{\dot x}{\dot y} = \frac{x(x^2-y^2)}{y^2} = x \biggl( x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{y^2} - 1 \biggr) \to L \cdot (L^2 \cdot 0-1) = -L$$ as $y \to +\infty$. So we have, say, $dx/dy < -L/2$ for all sufficiently large $y$. But that's a contradiction, since it would imply $x \to -\infty$ as $y \to +\infty$. Hence $L=0$, as we wanted to show.

Comment: Ha, amazing, yet again a clever way of thinking. Thank you for sharing your insights. I'm glad I asked this question here and you happened to see it, because I've learned a lot, and I will keep this trick in mind of considering $\dot x/\dot y$.

Comment: Well, thank you for asking such an interesting question! It would deserve some more upvotes, I think!